# Objective-C Runtime: What to put for size & alignment for class_addIvar?

Tags: objective-c, c, sizeof, memory-alignment, size-t

The [Objective-C Runtime provides the class_addIvar C function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addIvar):

```
BOOL class_addIvar(Class cls, const char *name, size_t size, 
                   uint8_t alignment, const char *types)
```

What do I put for `size` and `alignment`?

I'm adding an instance variable of type `UITextPosition *`, but no `UITextPosition` object is in scope. For `size`, can I just do `sizeof(self)`, where `self` is a subclass of `UITextField`? I.e., can I assume that a `UITextPosition` object is the same size as a `UITextField` object?

How do I get `alignment`?

Answer (score 7):

The documentation on this stuff is not very informative, which does reflect that generally you shouldn't be using it.  However, you can ask for the alignment:

```
char *texPosEncoding = @encode(UITextPosition);
NSUInteger textPosSize, textPosAlign;
NSGetSizeAndAlignment(textPosEncoding, &textPosSize, &textPosAlign);
class_addIvar(yourClass, "yourIvarName", textPosSize, textPosAlign, textPosEncoding);
```

Comment: The code here is referring to data structure alignment for an ivar reference to a `UITextPosition` object.  There's no UI alignment here.

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, the big question is 'why'. This only working on classes you're generating at runtime yourself, you can not add ivars to existing classes.

With that out of the way, in your case you're adding an ivar which is a pointer type, meaning they're all the same size. Its the size of the pointer, not the size of the object which matters.

From the documentation you linked then, you want size as `sizeof(UITextPosition*)` and alignment as `log2(sizeof(UITextPosition*))`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I realized I didn't actually have to add an ivar anyhow because I just noticed that `UITextInput` has a `beginningOfDocument` ivar, which is exactly what I wanted. So, I'll use that. But, this is great to know. Thanks! I understand how you came up with `size`, but how did you come up with `alignment`? Why is it log2 of the size?

Comment: It's log2 because `class_addIvar` does `1<<align`, which is equivalent to `pow(2, align)`.  See the [`class_addIvar` manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addIvar).