# What does class_addIvar's alignment do in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Someone has ask the same question before:[Objective-C Runtime: What to put for size & alignment for class_addIvar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942345/objective-c-runtime-what-to-put-for-size-alignment-for-class-addivar)
But it's not fully resolved.

The functions declaration is as follows:

```
BOOL class_addIvar(Class cls, const char *name, size_t size, uint8_t alignment, const char *types)
```

Which is used to add an instance variable to a dynamically created class in Objective-C.

The forth argument, `uint8_t alignment`, is described in Apple's documentation:

`The instance variable's minimum alignment in bytes is 1<<align. The minimum alignment of an instance variable depends on the ivar's type and the machine architecture. For variables of any pointer type, pass log2(sizeof(pointer_type))`.

In some tutorials, it's just claimed that if the ivar is pointer type, I should use `log2(sizeof(pointer_type))`; if the ivar is value type, I should use `sizeof(value_type)`. But why? Can someone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to learn where these values come from, you'll need to look at architecture specific ABI references, for OSX and iOS, they can be found here: [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html), [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html).

Each of those documents should have a section titled 'Data Types and Data Alignment', which helps to explain those values for the specific architecture.

In practice, since C11, you can use the `_Alignof` operator to have the compiler give you the correct value for a specific type (as it already needs to know this in order to generate proper machine code), so you can create a `class_addIvar` that looks something like this:

```
class_addIvar(myClass, "someIvar", sizeof(int), log2(_Alignof(int)), @encode(int))
```

Which should take care of all those gory details of the underlying type for you.

Comment: When it comes to pointer type, I don't think _Alignof should be used in class_addIvar. In Apple's documentation, log2(sizeof(pointer_type)) should be used. I now understand the concept of data alignment, but still don't understand the alignment of pointer type in class_addIvar.

Comment: @ZhuShengq My Bad. You should do `log2(_Alignof(type))`. Reason being that inside `class_addIvar`, it adjusts the alignment by doing a `1 << alignment` operation for you.

Comment: Thanks, you just clarify my confusion! log2(_Alignof(type)) makes everything clear. But Apple seems to want us use _Alignof(int) as for value type, log2(_Alignof(int *)) as for pointer type. Maybe Apple does a value/pointer type check in class_addIvar? I also experiment NSGetSizeAndAlignment with some value types and pointer types. An interesting thing is their size is always equal to align. Maybe on other platforms it doesn't hold that equolity

Comment: @ZhuShengqi for any platform, alignof(type) is <= sizeof(type). So, if you're in doubt, you can use log2(sizeof(type)), and that will always be valid. On some platforms, it is valid for, example, for a 32-bit integer to only be 8-bit aligned, but that doesn't mean it isn't valid for it to also be 32-bit aligned, as 32 is a multiple of 8.

Comment: @ZhuShengqi also, no, you should always use log2(alignof(type)), even if it's not a pointer type. class_addIvar always does 1 << alignment. You can verify that by looking at objc-runtime-new.mm, over at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-647/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm

Comment: Thanks! I finally get this thing clear : ) Thank you for answering me with such great patience.